# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que recargue la página correctamente con PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario que debe de hacer lo siguiente:

- Si el usuario y la contraseña coinciden con los establecidos, se debe
  de abrir una nueva página
- Si el usuario y la contraseña no coinciden, debe de aparecer un
  mensaje
- Si no hay sesión establecida no se carga ninguna página excepto la
  del formulario

La cuestión es que no consigo que, si el usuario y la contraseña no son correctos, la página recargue correctamente, ya que el mensaje sigue apareciendo. Además, me gustaría que me pudiérais decir que lo que he escrito hasta ahora está correcto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['contrasena'])){
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

    if($usuario == 'admin' && $contrasena == 'Fdwes!21'){
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $contrasena;
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: intento.php');
    }else{
        header('Location: login.php?error=1');
    }
}


if(isset($_POST['error']) and $_POST['error'] == 1) {
  $error = '<h3><b>Usuario y contraseñas erróneos. Inténtelo de nuevo.</b></h3>';
} else {
  $error = '';
}

?>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url(estilo.css);
    </style>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <form action='' method='post'>
            <div>
                <label>Usuario:</label>
                <input type='text' name='usuario'/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Contraseña:</label>
                <input type='password' name='contrasena'/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type='submit' value='Login' name='login'/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>

    <?php if (isset($error)) echo $error; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Nota: uso GET para ir comprobando el código, pero en realidad el formulario funcionaría con POST.

Comment: Recuerda que lo que pongas siempre en un `header()` debe ir antes de cualquier salida de texto, sino te dará error y no se procesará. En tu caso haces un echo justo antes del `header` y tiene toda la pinta de ser eso el error. Si quitas lo del echo deberia funcionarte bien, pero sin mensaje. Si quieres mostrarlo como sea, entonces planteate enviarlo mediante un parámetro más en tu petición pero usando header(location), y si ese parámetro existe lo muestras en tu HTML.

Comment: Y si el mensaje lo pongo en un alert, cambiaría algo?
Es que la secuencia tiene que ser que salga el mensaje y luego se recargue automáticamente la página

Comment: Creo que eso que me planteas es demasiado complejo, ya que en principio sólo debo de usar PHP. En cualquier caso, muchas gracias una vez más @masterguru

Comment: El problema es que la recarga debe ser automática

Comment: Y lo de header('Location: login.php?error=1'); me permite lanzar el mensaje antes de recargar la página?

Comment: Podrías insertar en mi código lo de if(isset($...? Es que no visualizo lo que me propones

Comment: Acabo de poner ambas soluciones posibles (sin ajax)... pruebalas a ver cual te convence. (tenia una fallo y he tenido que actualizarlo de nuevo, me habia dejado el echo antes del header)

Comment: Buenas @masterguru He cambiado el get por post y ahora no sale el mensaje de error por pantalla. He cambiado la última línea del código (la que hace que salga por pantalla) para ver si así salía, pero nada ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se visualice?

Comment: Eso es porque el "error" no es POST, sino GET... es decir, si lo pasas asi: `header("Location: login.php?error=1");` lo que estas pasando es un GET, por lo tanto cambia esto: `$_POST['error']` por  `$_GET['error']` en todas partes donde lo estes poniendo y te funcionará

Comment: Parece que ese era el problema. Muchas gracias una vez más @masterguru

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Con javascript

Si te dejan usar javascript, esto podria solucionarte el tema.
Modificar esto:

```php
echo "<b>Usuario y contraseñas erróneos</b>";
header("Refresh:");
```

por esto:

```php
echo "
<script>
alert('Usuario y contraseñas erróneos')
window.location.href='login.php'
</script>
";
```

Eso te muestra el mensaje de error en un alert, y al cerrarlo te devuelve a la página inicial

### Con PHP

Y si todo tiene que ser en PHP entonces seria algo asi para que usando `header()` le pasemos un parámetro de error a la página, y usando un condicional comprobamos si existe la posible variable pasada con el código de error y mostrariamos o no un texto descriptivo del error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET["usuario"]) && isset($_GET["contrasena"])){
    $usuario = $_GET["usuario"];
    $contrasena = $_GET["contrasena"];

    if($usuario == "admin" && $contrasena == "password"){
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION["contrasena"] = $contrasena;
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: sesion.php");
    }else{
        header("Location: login.php?error=1");
    }
}


if(isset($_GET["error"]) and $_GET["error"] == 1) {
  $msg = "<h3><b>Usuario y contraseñas erróneos. Vuelve a probar.</b></h3>";
} else {
  $msg = "";
}

?>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url(estilo.css);
    </style>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <form action="login.php" method="get">
            <div>
                <label>Usuario:</label>
                <input type="text" name="usuario"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" name="contrasena"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <?=$msg?>
</body>

</html>
```

### Con PHP y HTML

Y en este caso lo que hacemos es mostrar durante x segundos el mensaje de error, para que automáticamente después regrese a la página del login, gracias al meta tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET["usuario"]) && isset($_GET["contrasena"])){
    $usuario = $_GET["usuario"];
    $contrasena = $_GET["contrasena"];

    if($usuario == "admin" && $contrasena == "password"){
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION["contrasena"] = $contrasena;
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: sesion.php");
    }else{
        echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>      
    <title>Error en login</title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=\'login.php\'" />    
  </head>    
  <body> 
    <h3><b>Usuario y contraseñas erróneos. En 5 segundos será redirigido de nuevo a la página de login.</b></h3>
  </body>  
</html>
';
die();
    }
}
?>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url(estilo.css);
    </style>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>

        <form action="login.php" method="get">
            <div>
                <label>Usuario:</label>
                <input type="text" name="usuario"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" name="contrasena"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vale. Creo que ya. Es cierto que el mensaje se mantiene a pesar de que se recarga la página, pero creo que es la solución más cercana a lo que planteaba. Muchas gracias una vez más @masterguru

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro (de todos modos aun me extraña que la solución con javascript no te haya funcionado, tambien deberia hacerlo)... borremos comentarios para eliminar ruido de la pregunta y esta respuesta, gracias!

Comment: He agregado una opción más a la respuesta, que seria con PHP y HTML, y usando el `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` en el `<head>`. Quizás te guste más que lo visto hasta ahora. La respuesta de @xabikip me ha dado la idea. Saludos!

Comment: Definitivamente, la etiqueta `meta` es la mejor opción.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer que aparezca el mensaje de "Usuario y contraseñas erróneos" y a los X segundos se haga un refresh de la pagina sin el mensaje.
La función header() permite decirle cuando hacer el refresh de esta manera
`header("Refresh: $sec; url=index.php");`

El código entero te quedaría así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_GET["usuario"]) && isset($_GET["contrasena"])){
    $usuario = $_GET["usuario"];
    $contrasena = $_GET["contrasena"];

    if($usuario == "admin" && $contrasena == "password"){
        $_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
        $_SESSION["contrasena"] = $contrasena;
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header("Location: sesion.php");
    }else{
        // Aqui rediriges a la misma pagina con el param error=1
        header('Location: login.php?error=1');
    }
}

?>
<head>
    <style>
        @import url(estilo.css);
    </style>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 
        // Si tiene el param error = 1 muestras el mensaje y si no, no.
        if(isset($_GET["error"]) && $_GET["error"] == 1){
            echo "<b>Usuario y contraseñas erróneos</b>";
            //después de mostrar el mensaje, a los $sec refrescas sin el error = 1
            $sec = "10";
            header("Refresh: $sec; url=login.php"); 
        }else{ ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                

                <form action="login.php" method="get">
                    <div>
                        <label>Usuario:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="usuario"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Contraseña:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="contrasena"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        <?php }
    ?>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Tendrás que ajustar el tiempo que quieras en segundos en el param `$sec = "10";`

Lo ideal sería usar javaScript y hacer un código mejor, pero esta es una manera simple que por lo que comentas te puede servir.

Comment: Diria que estamos en lo mismo que al principio... segun la página del manual de [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php) dice lo siguiente:  **Recuerde que header() debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde PHP.** y con tu propuesta estamos mandando un echo antes del header igualmente.  Quizas funcione, no lo se, pero no deberia segun el manual o quizas arroja un error en el log y funciona igual.

Comment: Es cierto que pone eso en la documentación, pero funciona y tampoco arroja ningún error ni warning en el log.

Comment: Tienes razón, lo he comprobado y no da error. Es curioso, ni un notice ni nada. En el ejemplo que hay en la propia página de la documentación, entre sus comentarios,  lo ponen al reves, primero el refresh y luego el echo, que aunque tu respuesta no de error, me parece más correcto eso.  acabo de agregar algo parecido en mi respuesta, pero solo con HTML y el `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` que viene a ser lo mismo, pero sin depender del header() del PHP por si acaso.

Comment: @masterguru y @xabikip, probablemente en servidor local funciona porque puede haber un búfer que espera a tener determinada cantidad de información para enviar al navegador, pero muchos servidores no lo tienen configurado y es donde va a fallar. Lo mejor es enviar siempre los encabezados antes de cualquier contenido o usar la etiqueta `<meta refresh...>`. Más información sobre control de salida: https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.outcontrol.php